# JQuery Drag and drop Save positions

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, drag-and-drop

I'm using the JQuery drag and drop to create a dashboard used on websites such as www.bbc.com. Is it possible to save the coordinates of the control after dragging and dropping the controls? if so, anyone have a website or article they would recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the coordinates of the controls you can just use
http://api.jquery.com/offset/ after the dragging has stopped and then saves those coordinates to a database.

But if your elements snap to a grid you might want to calculate which grid column and which position in that column the element is.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not run a function on the drop that sends the coordinates and size of the control in question using ajax to the server and save it?

If it's the "normal" drag and drop then you have a `stop`function that you could use.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({    stop:
function(event, ui) { $.ajax(...) }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to save them?

You can write a function to save the position inside the container, when a users finish to move the controls an event is fired:

```
 stop: function(event, ui) { ... }
```

There you can get the controls position using the offset function.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the ui.position attribute.

```
$("#foo").draggable();
$("#foo").bind("dragstop", function (e, ui)
{
    console.log(ui.position.top);
    console.log(ui.position.left);
});
```

The event can be bound within the draggable method but I've left it like this for clarity.

[More Information](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).draggable({revert:true});
```

this will help your drag control move to its original position when drag is released

Answer (score 0):

drag and drop

```
$('#page_list').sortable({

            update  : function(event, ui)
          {
              $("#save_arrangement").show();
              var id_array = new Array();
                 $('#page_list tr').each(function(){
                    id_array.push($(this).attr("id"));
                 });
             console.log(id_array);
             $("#save_arrangement").on("click", function () {
                  $.ajax({
                    url:"/quotations/save_arrangement",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{'id_array':id_array},
                    success:function(success)
                    {
                     swal({
                        title:"Arrangement has been saved",
                        type:"success"
                     },
                     function(isConfirm) {
                          if (isConfirm) {
                                  location.reload(); 
                          }
                        });

                    },
                  });
             });
          }
      });
```